# Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type

Tags: typescript

I have written an abstract base class that allows asynchronous instantiation (i.e. to load data before returning the instance). I would like to prohibit users from using the constructor as they would get an uninitialized instance, but I am getting the following error if I make the constructor protected:

> The 'this' context of type 'typeof InheritedController' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Constructor'.
> Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.

This is my code:

```
type Constructor<T> = new () => T;

export default abstract class BaseController {
  static async create<T extends BaseController>(
    this: Constructor<T>
  ): Promise<T> {
    const controller = new this();
    await controller.initialize();
    return controller;
  }

  protected constructor() {}

  protected async initialize() {
    console.log('Initialising asynchronously...');
  }
}

class InheritedController extends BaseController {
  protected async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    // await loading data
  }
}

const controller = await InheritedController.create()
```

I cannot get my head around this error message and was unable to find any solution so far.

Comment: If you want the constructor to always be protected, why _is_ it public in Constructor?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I don't know what you mean, could you point it out in more detail please? Constructor is a type, how would I make it protected?

Comment: from the logic point of view constructor is always protected in abstract class

Comment: Not sure why `typeof InheritedController extends new () => InheritedController` evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 0):

I would not attempt to make the `constructor` and the `initialize` methods protected. Keep them public. Instead, change the constructor and its signature so that no one can construct an uninitialised instance! Pass all the data that it needs as arguments. You can keep the static `create` function if you change the pattern just a bit:

```
interface ControllerConstructor<T, C> {
  new (options: T): C;
  initOptions(): Promise<T>;
}

export default abstract class BaseController<T> {
  static async create<T, C extends BaseController<T>>(this: ControllerConstructor<T, C>): Promise<C> {
    return new this(await this.initOptions());
  }
  constructor(options: T) {}
}

class InheritedController extends BaseController<void> {
  static async initOptions(): Promise<void> {
    // await loading data
  }
}

const controller = await InheritedController.create()
```