# Allowing a parent class to access configurations from a child class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `BaseModel` class in which I'm adding common static methods (fetch, fetchAll, create, etc.). I have different models that extend this class as to use its methods.

```js
import { fetcher } from "../utils/fetch";

export type BaseModelConfigType = {
  singularName: string,
  pluralName: string
}

export default class BaseModel {
  constructor(cfg: BaseModelConfigType) {
    if (!cfg.singularName || !cfg.pluralName) {
      throw new Error('BaseModel requires a singularName and pluralName');
    }
  }

  static async fetch(pluralName: string, id: string): Promise<any> {
    return await fetcher.get(`${pluralName}/${id}`);
  }
}

export type SynapseType = {
  id?: string,
  text: string,
  created_at?: string,
  updated_at?: string
}

export class Synapse extends BaseModel {
  id?: string;
  text!: string;
  created_at?: string;
  updated_at?: string;

  static config = {
    singularName: 'synapse',
    pluralName: 'synapses'
  }

  constructor(data: SynapseType) {
    super(Synapse.config);

    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  static async fetch(id: string): Promise<Synapse> {
    const data: SynapseType = await super.fetch(Synapse.config.pluralName, id);
    return new Synapse(data);
  }
}

export class OtherModel extends Basemodel {...}
```

I feels as though it defeats the whole purpose of having the base model, if in each model that extends it I have to add a like named function as to pass in static properties.

Ideally, I'd like to use `super(Model.config)` in the child model constructor, and then make sure that the BaseModel has access to each child models config executing methods.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: "How might I achieve this?" just don't use static methods. It's not clear at all why you even have classes here when you're using them (at least in the example code you posted) purely as namespaces. Normal methods have access to `this` and then the whole problem disappears. Or alternatively have plain data classes with regular functions you export to manipulate them rather than trying to cram it into an inheritance model that wasn't designed for that.

Comment: Hey Jared, I simplified the the code a bit so that the example was more exact. However, the goal is to do a ORM style SDK for a javascript app, in which I define my models and can interact with them, rather directly with API endpoints. 

In doing that, my thought was (from patterns I see in ruby) that methods class `new`, `create`, `find`... should be static on the class, as they don't have to do with any instance. Where as other methods `update`, `destroy` would be on the instance.

Comment: Ok. What I would do (assuming I was required to use this architecture because I wouldn't if given the choice) is use `this` in the static methods (which [refers to the class object itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQgFzNglsNAEZgBO0AvNAMzqY56ElgBeAFAJQr2aZkBTbAFcyAO2jYAFvggA6UmV7QAvqhVA) rather than instances when used in static methods) to call the descendent class methods in the base class and then make abstract signatures for them in the base class so that subclasses are required by the compiler to implement them.

Comment: Ah, that's cool and works! Thank you. Do you say that you wouldn't use this architecture because of preference or is there a specific downside that you see?

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964610/1048572), using `new this(…)`

Comment: @SebastianScholl I added an answer that offers a cleaned-up version of your approach along with an alternative one. The comment from Bergi is also good.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaned up version of this approach would probably look something like this:

```
// This error throwing is unfortunate but there's
// no static abstact methods in TS. Ideally we'd
// like these to be compile-time enforced.
export default class BaseModel {
  static get singularName(): string {
    throw new Error('Must supply name in derived class!');
  }

  static get pluralName(): string {
    throw new Error('Must supply name in derived class!');
  }

  // "of" and "from" are also popular names for these kinds of
  // static object construction methods. 
  static async create(id: string): Promise<any> {
    throw new Error('Must override in derived class!');
  }
}

export type SynapseType = {
  id?: string,
  text: string,
  created_at?: string,
  updated_at?: string
}

export class Synapse extends BaseModel {
  id?: string;
  text!: string;
  created_at?: string;
  updated_at?: string;

  static singularName: 'synapse'
  static pluralName: 'synapses'

  constructor(data: SynapseType) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  static async create(id: string): Promise<Synapse> {
    const data = await fetcher.get(`${this.pluralName}/${id}`);
    return new Synapse(data);
  }
}
```

This has a few nice properties. Duplication is reduced. The now-useless base class constructor is gone. You'll get a fast error if you try to construct an object using a non-overriden static `create` method or forget to override the names, although it would be nicer if we could move those checks to compile-time. The return values of the async static creation methods are now more strongly-typed.

If you are going to do any real logic in those static methods that call constructors though I'd go ahead and use the type system to enforce *only* calling them that way:

```
class Foo extends BaseModel {
    static singularName: 'foo'
    static pluralName: 'foos'

    // This creates both a unique value and a unique
    // *type* because unlike most things in TS enums
    // are nominally-typed and private means only this
    // class can access it, the constructor is locked.
    private static unique = (() => { enum Bar { _ = '' }; return Bar })()
    constructor(_lock: typeof Foo.unique, public readonly id: string) {
        super();
    }

    static async create(id: string): Promise<Foo> {
    return new Foo(Foo.unique, id);
  }
}

// Can no longer call new Foo
const foo = new Foo(Foo.unique, 'abc123'); // error
const bar = Foo.create('abc123'); // fine
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQKYCckHsmgC6TQd2gHYDmocoArgQGbqaUCGmCoARuZlpMggOSwBQIUAVShYmRtADGoei3H0pHALYJsqACbxCEAMoA6UAEkNCegBtzAT1C5eGwWHPQA1s2wJY70S2ZTUygAO0OYIALSY0KqI1OhSCBr6-AgAHoG0oKZU9OTmHFLm9LDwAEJFCACymgjmoADe-KBiEpEyRGpihES59EgAcvSqABQAlABczUhd9Y1NnHjCCLigAKIo6EM8FeTiYuSBgdbCg8w6plMAbgmgBUWwAIQ8IwDcswC+-LMKraDtHIfkJAWAbDcaTaYNObzVDLAhLVbrJCbba7WD7Q42AgnUgETLIaBXDQ3QrFR4vd6fJpCABEqCo1NkBCJ1KoaGUDN6zAssFE6UCPQwWNU8BoGA8XlALkIWlAdNmQm+0llLAAVgglDdUARxEhyEpoFrQKp1FpDF8WkqilYCDIpEgzEwhtANBMdV0wQAFNlwBAAHnoBCsAD4ZlDsAs4cs1mgkVsdhxUFcUM7TrjzgTrrdSU9Xk0Ph9kmkMpgrIFmLprfRAl5wKXmABeUOkDQAfldmCmxAANLMmClMO3O0Qe007Q6EgB9Rht8Hd2b7DSMSfTwddfgF1LpJD5EnwCtY6vMVJMJmlcpVUy1SHNmdu4i5rDH+6r++zMdLjRTzC3jtdB8Lj8vx-IdXnNSQZFgLoBRBBAJj4StDx4MCfgBIFzBguDYAQrxYCQt8tR1PVMA2RcJAmfcqxrOsRibJo0TLJFyShAB5VV1UwfQ7mgIgCCGbA4C7TJGHoJjQALOiLRkK0bRue0lydF1ZyIT1vS8X0KMPENr1HAiOFI+hQEbehcHoaAOCoNQpC4JB9D+IYAAMABI6n42B9FQ4ETjeYBnOdN57NEpp7ToJBcUjUANK8IZ9NE-NPizeAADFUFEY8EFPUAyi8C8alo0BAkuJdmnAigCGgABHcgG1AIZRkMrSYnIZRMt6epQAnQzQB4HgxOeUBgsBXEygwN4RlGWYdO1DsiI2CdzFQKQXAmEsyzpUBktQfRKAqqrBP5FhnBkOSNC1I5nRfZS8qhejkFGB880pOZFSkrCZPfR1zqUlSAh9X0Nq0ib+rUQbFmWDahg2raysqhBBOdWL10+IQAGEA2EUR5uIZAbgsWpwo2-h-Cm0AaFERt8ZSiGUqhnbYa6uQpAARgAJgAZhzQndNYVrG0h96EE2BmWfZl5QCEKhCAQIA)

### Edit

You asked in the comments how I'd do it. I might do something like this:

```
interface BaseModel {
  new (...args: any[]): any
  a: string
}

const factory = <C extends BaseModel>(Clazz: C) => {
  return async (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>): Promise<InstanceType<C>> => {
    const resp = await fetch('some-url');
    const data = await resp.json();
    return new Clazz(...args);
  }
}

class Foo {}
class Bar { static a = 'a' }

const makeFoo = factory(Foo); // fails, no 'a'
const makeBar = factory(Bar);
```

Now the static members *are* compile-checks: you'll get immediate feedback in your IDE if you fail to match the BaseModel's interface, and we don't have to do any hackery like I did above with enums to lock the constructor, we can just not export the concrete classes and only export the `makeWhatever` factory functions.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QLIHsAmEANsgN4BQyyIEA7sgBQB0LcUA5hgFzJwgCeAbQC6ASh59+lXjwxgooduQC+5cglwg5yeAjC4o-ZAF5kAHgDCyCAA9IIfBjSYcBYgD4GFonABevngtRE3cyaSgIMABXKBBeDH4QBEYWJjZOQM05KCi9AwAFNjgAW0joDEt3cWR8qFxi4CwzAEktMD4kABV+AAcIStDjUIoqKg025AiMHpNeWjhgMB1IhAALBgByDHqIAFoYog3RAG5pMayl-Dh22bh5xcmIaaYAK22QBhOzx+jY6jpkN4-L5mKwOBgvlRVKp1D4ME4AGK4XBkVQIOFOdBQMjIOTXYDJOCzDZwDbIGHjbTFOAAawgSJRpl0+kMDAZJ2QAHpOdQUSSNuoLshqXSsbNmQZ+AwsV8gA)

Like Ruby, JS is a multi-paradigm language: if the OO approach seems awkward you can always mix in a little functional code to sweeten the taste.